# Почему не центрируется в IE?

Tags: css

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите плз, почему в Эксплорере не центрирует блок div по стилю margin:0px auto? Спасибо.

Comment: ps: Если вы нашли подходящий ответ отметьте его галочкой!Просто напоминаю :)

Comment: а какая версия "Ослика"?

Answer (score 3):

Советы называються так: я не заню но покажу как!

Что бы центрировать блок див в ие через margin:0 auto;
нужно что бы в блока были фискированая ширина.

Работает все и в ие6.
ТОЛЬКО ШИРИНА НУЖНА НА БЛОК.

Comment: вот именно так и надо!)все почему-то забыли о таком понятии как свойство hasLayout...плюсую!

Comment: так ведь есть фиксированная ширина в пикселах!..

Answer (score 0):

Эксплорер - это вообще беда для веб разработчиков, то не будь его, процесс разработки не был бы таким занимательным и интересным =) Вашу проблему можно попробовать решить несколькими способами:

> 1) align:center;
>
> 2) margin:0 auto

Comment: Так я же пишу, стиль margin:0 auto ничего не решает

Comment: А разве есть такое свойство align:center?

Comment: Свойства align нету. Это я ошибся. Align есть у самого div`а.
"<div align='center'></div>"

Comment: Тогда нужно добавлять лишний div, неужели без этого никак? Я видел сайты где обходились без этого...

Comment: Не надо ничего добавлять!!! Укажите это свойство в своем диве!

Comment: Не работает так!!! А вот если для body прописать text-align:center вот тогда работает!:)) Всем спасибо!

Comment: Так это у вас не div был не по центру, а весь документ, точнее его видимая часть - body. Надо бы вам подучить основы верстки...

Answer (score 0):

О боже:)

```
<div style="text-align: center"></div>
<div style="margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Оба варианта отработают одинаково, если больше нет никаких элементов на странице :) Второй вариант будет работать в ие, если использовать DOCTYPE!

Comment: А как Вы думаете, есть еще элементы на странице?:) Использую вот эдакий <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">, и не работает...

Comment: а зачем Вы используете этот доктайп?

Comment: Ну незнаю, в справочнике прочел)) А какой надо?

Comment: @Aviko DOCTYPE нужно знать как отче наш, ибо тсюда идет множество проблем и несостыковок!

Comment: Ну так научите меня этой "отче наш"!))

Comment: `<!doctype html>` - этого более чем достаточно. =)

Comment: Именно, и любой jsкрипт с ним подружится) хотя не рекомендовано! А в случае 5 страничек кода он ваще н... не нужен этот doctype! К примеру для ПС(поисковых систем) он тупо серобуромалиновй на ощупь!